# How to add automator scripts to apple shortcuts?

Tags: applescript, automator, siri, airplay, shortcuts-app

I am trying to run a simple automation I recorded via Automator app, that will open my AirPlay devices and start screen mirroring to my TV (named as TV).

I was able to record functional automation, but my final goal is to be able to run this automation via Siri from my phone. Since iPhone doesn't know anything about Automator App, it just knows Shortcuts, I need to find a way to run this automator script via shortcuts.

When I was trying to create my own shortcut on Macbook via Shortcuts app, I wasn't able to make it happen.

Note: There is an "solution" for Monteray (found online) to do this in Shortcuts via Apple scripts and I've tried that, but script that controls the preferences panels is outdated and no longer works in Sonoma. (so you can either try to fix that one, because I can't do that, or continue with my original question)

So how can I run my recorded automation via Shortcuts app?

Or else how am I suppose to tackle this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Shortcuts are executed on the machine they are launched. So there are no way you can activate an Automator script on your Mac from an iPhone, except from taking remote control of your Mac , which is likely not what you want, and will not be smooth.